# My code is broken with arrays, but I cannot figure it out

Tags: php, arrays

I cannot figure out why $promobill($count_i) does not print anything out. I have worked with this for hours beating my head against the wall. Any ideas?

Is $promobill an array or not? It should be, but I am uncertain whether it is formed correctly. Does this line yield an array of random elements from the original array or only ONE random element and assign it to a variable $promobill?

```
$promo_bill = array_rand($site_promotions, $app_count);
```

Here is my full code:

```
    <?php

$site_promotions = array(
    'Free appetiser - orders over $3,000',
    '$100 off first time orders!',
    'testing...'
);

$appetisers = array(
    array('Pomegranate Shrimp','Jumbo shrimp sauteed with shitake mushrooms, herbs and pomegranate molasses.','#'),
    array('Hummus','Chick peas blended with tahini, garlic and lemon juice; topped with olive oil.','#'),
    array('Baba Ghannouj','Roasted eggplant blended with tahini, fresh garlic, parsley and lemon juice; topped with olive oil.','#'),
    array('Persian SaladPersian Salad','Freshly diced cucumbers, tomatoes and red onions tossed with lemon juice and a pinch of mint.','#'),
    array('Kash-Ke-Bademjan','Roasted eggplant purees with onion, garlic, mint and Kashk (aged, dried yogurt); topped with caramelized onions and kask.','#'),
    array('Must O Khiar','Homemade yogurt, freshly diced cucumbers and mint. Smooth and refreshing!','#'),
    array('Moosir','Persian Shallot finely sliced mixed with thich homemade yogurt. Try it, you\'ll like it.','#'),
    array('Olovieh','Persian potato salad with chopped chicken breast, pickles, peas, shredded carrots & mayonnaise.','#'),
    array('Caspian Eggplant','Mix of sweet charbroiled eggplant, tomato, onion & garlic topped with moosir.','#'),
    array('Pomegranate Mushrooms','Your choice of mushrooms flavored with exotic herbs, garlic, olive oil & pomegranate molasses.','#'),
    array('Dolmeh Felfel','Two bell peppers stuffed with basmati rice, cracked wheat, herbs & vegtables, baked in tomato saffron sauce.','#'),
    array('Dolmeh','Grape leaves stuffed with rice, tomato, onion, herbs & spices in tomato saffron sauce.','#'),
    array('Borani','Fresh spinach sautéed with onions and garlic in extra virgin olive oil and mixed with homemade yogurt.','#'),
    array('Spicy Pomegranate Wings','Charbroiled chicken wings with pomegranate glaze (7). Yummy, yummy, yummy!','#'),
    array('Falafel','Chickpeas seasoned and lightly fried served with tahini sauce.','#'),
    array('Persian Garden Salad','Crispy romaine, spring mix, red onions, cucumbers, cherry tomato, olives & Bulgarian cheese.','#')
);

$app_count = count($appetisers);
$promo_bill = array_rand($site_promotions, $app_count);

foreach($appetisers as $dish)
    {
        $count_i=key($dish);

        echo'
            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">

                <div class="sponsorFlip">
                        <a class="group1" href="img/appetisers.jpg" title="'.$dish[0].'">       
                        <img class="sponsorIMG" src="img/appetisers_t.jpg" alt="Donya Catering menu" />
                    </a>    
                    <div class="dish_name">'.$dish[0].'</div>                   
                </div>

                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">'.$dish[1].'</div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">
                        <a class="sponsorLINK" href="promos/.'$promobill($count_i)'.">'.$promo_bill($count_i).'</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Because it should be `$promo_bill[$count_i]`? I'm pretty sure that a bunch of other stuff is wrong too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to build an array of promotions for each dish, why not simply grab one promotion per item?

```
foreach ($appetisers as $dish) {
    $promotion = $site_promotions[array_rand($site_promotions, 1)];
    // use $promotion
}
```

Comment: The same promotion might be selected multiple times this way, unlike when using `array_rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. See it in action at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/recraig/zz7HV/10/)...

```
<?php

$promotions = array();
$promos = array();
$promotions1 = array();

foreach (explode("\n", file_get_contents('http://donyacatering.com/st/wp-content/themes/DonyaCatering/data/promotions.txt')) as $promotions1) {
    $promotions[] = explode(",", $promotions1);
}

$appetisers = array(
    array('Pomegranate Shrimp','Jumbo shrimp sauteed with shitake mushrooms, herbs and pomegranate molasses.','http://donyacatering.com/'),
    array('Hummus','Chick peas blended with tahini, garlic and lemon juice; topped with olive oil.','http://donyacatering.com/'),
    array('Baba Ghannouj','Roasted eggplant blended with tahini, fresh garlic, parsley and lemon juice; topped with olive oil.','http://donyacatering.com/'),
    array('Persian SaladPersian Salad','Freshly diced cucumbers, tomatoes and red onions tossed with lemon juice and a pinch of mint.','http://donyacatering.com/')
);

                foreach($appetisers as $id=>$dish)
                {
                    $r=rand(0, count($promotions) - 1);
                    $promos[$id][0] = $promotions[$r][0];
                    $promos[$id][1] = $promotions[$r][1];
                    echo'
                    <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">     
                        <div class="sponsorFlip">
                            <a class="group1" href="http://donyacatering.com/st/wp-content/themes/DonyaCatering/img/appetisers.jpg" title="'.$dish[0].'<br>'.$dish[1].'">       
                            <img class="sponsorIMG" src="http://donyacatering.com/st/wp-content/themes/DonyaCatering/img/appetisers_t.jpg" alt="Donya Catering menu" />
                            </a>    
                            <div class="dish_name">'.$dish[0].'</div>                   
                        </div>

                        <div class="sponsorData">
                            <div class="sponsorURL">
                                <a class="sponsorLINK" href="http://donyacatering.com/st/wp-content/themes/DonyaCatering/promos/'.$promos[$id][1].'" title="'.$promos[$id][1].'">'.$promos[$id][0].'</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ';
                }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be counting the array appetizers, then trying to use that count for site_promotions, instead maybe it should dbe:

```
$app_count = count($site_promotions);
$promo_bill = array_rand($site_promotions, $app_count);
```

Comment: Problem is I need to come up with a randomly selected promotion for each appetiser. The promotion will be displayed on the backside of the menu flip photo for each appetiser as a visitor clicks the photo.